# REST query correct timing/positioning

Tags: rest, xamarin, binding

I built a cross-platform mobile application using Xamarin but my question should apply to other frameworks as well.

I have two pages, the 1st has a list of items of the same Object. Clicking an item leads to the 2nd page that is populated using information based on the item that was selected using data binding. The information are retrieved using a REST GET query. My question is if there is a best practice on when to perform the query: Should I do the query in the 1st page inside the method that is triggered when the item is clicked (thus, before loading the 2nd page) and pass this information to the 2nd page or the 2nd page should be loaded passing the item that was selected and then perform the query in the 2nd page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to do it in the 2nd page. 
I think it's more practical and time efficient. I never had any problem with this method and also everything worked fine for me.

But I think **the best method is to use a 3rd page**. You pass the data from the second page in the 3rd page, and call the service you want. You put all the logic in there. Than using databinding you access those data and you render them in your page in any way you want. This way you seperate entirely the logic of the app from the interface. **Of course you use the 3rd case when you need to call the service to access new data**.

In my cases I used to use the 2nd method you mentioned becouse I already had all the data and didn't have the need to call the service one other time.